# how can i use referenced libraries

Tags: java, android

Hi I made one jar file with 3 classes.They work fine they are supporting file for getting HXM data.Now when i made jar i want to use it in my next project.I imported it and now it is in referenced libraries.But i can not find how can i use the libraries.  in old project from i take the 3 .class file they have the paths: sk.csabi.hxm.*

but now how can i import and use them?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should i use a jar file ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605145/how-should-i-use-a-jar-file)

Comment: oh thanks i will check it if it is i delete my post

Comment: i need eclipse variant, it is not good for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using java library in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285986/using-java-library-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but it seems like you're asking how to add the JAR to your project classpath in Eclipse.

What you're looking to do is add the libraries to your project's build path (the class path that will be used while compiling). In Eclipse, you can do this by right-clicking your project and choosing `Properties` (or hitting `[Alt]+[Enter]` when the project is selected in `Project Explorer`, `Navigator` or `Package Explorer` views) and then `Java Build Path` from the sidebar and the `Libraries` tab where you can add JARs.

Note the difference between `Add JARs` and `External JARs` is that `External JARs` will add an external dependency in your project since the absolute path to the JAR on your filesystem will be put into your project's configuration. With `Add JARs` you can select JARs from within your workspace.

I find it to be a good practice to create a `lib` folder (at the same level as my `src` folder) and put all my JARs in there and then add them to the build path with the `Add JARs` option. This makes the project portable since there are only relative paths referring to resources within the project rather than absolute paths or resources from other workspace projects.

Comment: and mazbe the problem is there the package name is (default package)

Comment: '*ok but how can i import it to activity*' What do you mean? An Android `Activity` is just another Java class - you would import other classes just as you would anywhere else, use the `import` statement: `import sk.csabi.hxm.*`.

Comment: '*there the package name is (default package)*' - I thought you said the package of the classes that you wanted to use was `sk.csabi.hxm`?

Comment: it where at the project where from the classes are, but when i created jar it created default package

Comment: That doesn't seem possible to me unless you've compiled the classes and then JARed the `.class` files without putting them into the correct folder hierarchy - on other words, you JAR has been built incorrectly. How did you create the JAR?

Comment: javac cf hxmlib.jar A.class B.class like that

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing exactly (and rather than trying to figure it out here in the comments) - why don't you just use the `Export` option in Eclipse to create your JAR? Right click your project, choose `Export`. In the dialog select `JAR file`. This should create the correct JAR file for your project. Try using this JAR in your second project.